# NSInternalInconsistencyException Cannot set the result on a completed task

Tags: ios, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-sdk-ios

Getting this crash sometimes, while trying to sign in. Using Amplify pod version 1.0.5. This was preceded by (1) auth session expired, (2) password reset. Probably, something left not cleaned up. What I am looking for is, are there any additional debugs I can enable in AWS/Amplify SDK?

```
2020-10-13 12:36:45.287376-0700 MyApp[41441:3203375] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cannot set the result on a completed task.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001165c78db __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001155b0ac5 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001165c7735 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   AWSCore                             0x0000000110a1e52d -[AWSTaskCompletionSource setResult:] + 173
    4   AWSMobileClient                     0x0000000110c38135 $s15AWSMobileClientAAC6signIn8username8password14validationData17completionHandlerySS_SSSDyS2SGSgyAA04SignD6ResultVSg_s5Error_pSgtctF + 2773
    5   AmplifyPlugins                      0x0000000111477315 $s14AmplifyPlugins22AWSMobileClientAdapterC6signIn8username8password14validationData17completionHandlerySS_SSSDyS2SGSgy0cD004SignG6ResultVSg_s5Error_pSgtctF + 197
    6   AmplifyPlugins                      0x0000000111478809 $s14AmplifyPlugins22AWSMobileClientAdapterCAA0cD8BehaviorA2aDP6signIn8username8password14validationData17completionHandlerySS_SSSDyS2SGSgy0cD004SignH6ResultVSg_s5Error_pSgtctFTW + 41
    7   AmplifyPlugins                      0x00000001114162bf $s14AmplifyPlugins29AuthenticationProviderAdapterC6signIn7request17completionHandlery0A008AuthSignG7RequestV_ys6ResultOyAG0klgN0VAG0K5ErrorOGctF + 1439
    8   AmplifyPlugins                      0x0000000111422a80 $s14AmplifyPlugins29AuthenticationProviderAdapterCAA0cD8BehaviorA2aDP6signIn7request17completionHandlery0A008AuthSignH7RequestV_ys6ResultOyAI0lmhO0VAI0L5ErrorOGctFTW + 16
    9   AmplifyPlugins                      0x000000011145ad35 $s14AmplifyPlugins22AWSAuthSignInOperationC4mainyyF + 789
    10  AmplifyPlugins                      0x000000011145b0ab $s14AmplifyPlugins22AWSAuthSignInOperationC4mainyyFTo + 43
    11  Amplify                             0x00000001110dc5dc $s7Amplify21AsynchronousOperationC5startyyF + 172
    12  Amplify                             0x00000001110dc61b $s7Amplify21AsynchronousOperationC5startyyFTo + 43
    13  Foundation                          0x000000011293de87 __NSOQSchedule_f + 227
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000118121d7f _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000118122db5 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000118125c95 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 552
    17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011812508f _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 849
    18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000118133632 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 351
    19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000118133fca _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 130
    20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001185149f7 _pthread_wqthread + 220
    21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000118513b77 start_wqthread + 15
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Getting same error when trying to change the initial user password for two users (one after another)